# How can I temporarily hide a specific index in an array?

Tags: java

I'm making a black jack game. My `AI` and `Player` classes both contain an arraylist that takes in all the cards they currently hold. However, I do not want to reveal the first card the dealer draws until later.

This is what it looks like now on initial set up:

```
player:
Total: 20
[(TEN, CLUBS), (TEN, SPADES)]

Dealer:
Total: 15
[(NINE, SPADES), (SIX, DIAMONDS)]
```

I want the Dealer to look more like `(xx,xx), (SIX, DIAMONDS)` until I decide to reveal it.

The main method where this method passes out the cards initially:

```
public static void setup(Deck deck, Player player, AI ai) {
    deck.draw(player);
    deck.draw(ai);
    deck.draw(player);
    deck.draw(ai);
    System.out.println("player: \n" + "Total: " + player.getValueOfHand() + "\n" + player.getPlayersCards() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Dealer: \n" + "Total: " + ai.getValueOfHand() + "\n" + ai.getAiCards() + "\n");
}
```

Deck class which contains draw methods:

```
/**
 * Draws a card for the player and adds it to players list of cards.
 * @param player the player 
 * @return the card that was drawn out of the deck.
 */
public Cards draw(Player player) {
    Cards card = listOfCards.get(0);
    player.addToPlayersCards(card);
    listOfCards.remove(card);
    pulledCards.add(card);
    return card;
}
/**
 * Draws a card for the ai and adds it to ai list of cards.
 * @param player the dealer 
 * @return the card that was drawn out of the deck.
 */
public Cards draw(AI ai) {
    Cards card = listOfCards.get(0);
    ai.addToAiCards(card);
    listOfCards.remove(card);
    pulledCards.add(card);
    return card;
}
```

Comment: So you are not asking anything about the algorithm, but just a way to change the output on console? If that's the case,  you could create a displayCards() method, and put some conditional show before your o/p display e.g. "System.out.println" .. not sure if thats what you are asking..?

Comment: well I would rather it be hardcoded in the algorithm because i plan to move this onto javafx later to build on it with a GUI. Basically every time im drawing a card for either player or dealer it goes into a array-list for player and dealer objects respectively. But i just want to know the easiest way that i can still simply print the array using simple print statement like I am now in such a way that the arraylist for the dealer has index(0) hidden until i decide other wise. Sorry if i misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Well in that case why not have it as a property of Card, e.g. visible.  A card couldn't be shared between a dealer and a player,  and therefore carries with itself the state whether it should be visible or not.  You can control this property in the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A card couldn't be shared between a dealer and a player, and therefore could carry with itself the state whether it should be visible.

Your code could look like something..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Application {

  public static class Card {

    public enum Suit {
      SPADE,
      HEART,
      DIAMOND,
      CLUB
    }

    Suit suit;
    int Value;
    Boolean visibleToOthers = false; // by default only card owner sees it.

    public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
      this.suit = suit;
      Value = value;
    }

    public void setVisible() {
      this.visibleToOthers = true;
    }

    public boolean isVisibleToOthers() {
      return this.visibleToOthers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Card{" + "suit=" + suit + ", Value=" + Value + '}';
    }
  }

  // .. other logic
  
  public void display(Card card) {
    if (card.isVisibleToOthers()) System.out.println("card.getValue()");
    else {
      System.out.println("X");
    }
  }

  public void display(List<Card> cards) {
    cards.stream().filter((c) -> c.isVisibleToOthers()).forEach((card) -> System.out.println(card));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Card c1 = new Card(Card.Suit.CLUB, 5);
    Card c2 = new Card(Card.Suit.DIAMOND, 2);
    c2.setVisible();
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>(Arrays.asList(new Card[] {c1, c2}));
    new Application().display(cards);
  }
}
```

Comment: i like the way you are showing as my card class is very similar with two enums one for rank and one for suit. The only thing is I wonder if there is a way that I can somehow work this visibility into the array (not sure how) so that I dont have to display cards one by one. Right now I just add a card to the arraylist for either the player or dealer and just print out the arraylist rather than the individual card. Basically so that I can just print someones hand like: [(TEN, CLUBS), (TEN, SPADES)] or [(XX, XX), (TEN, SPADES)]

Comment: Use your own print method (e.g. like the one I showed above display) and make it accept List<Card> instead of Card.  I added another overloaded method in the answer as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the information somewhere which cards are openly visible and which are still hidden. You could add an boolean to each card that indicates this. You could also add the openly visible cards to another list that is 'the table'. You have a lot of design freedom here.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't show your method: `getAiCards()` but I think you would want to pass in a boolean as an argument to the method to say if you want to reveal the first card. Like so:

```
void getAiCards(boolean revealFirstCard) {
    if (!revealFirstCard && aiCards.length > 0) {
        String[][] aiCardsClone = aiCards.clone();
        aiCardsClone[0][0] = "xx";
        aiCardsClone[0][1] = "xx";
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(aiCardsClone));
    } else {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(aiCards));
    }
}
```

When you call it and you don't want to reveal the card: `getAiCards(false)`

When you do want to reveal the first card: `getAiCards(true)`

Comment: the thing is it would be counterintuitive for the way I have it setup to make a two dimensional array with xx for example. I have it setup so that AI class has a field that is "private List<Cards> AiCards;" and the Cards objects that it takes in is actually constructed using a Suit and a Rank which are both enums. So i just want to be able to print the array rather than have to loop through each element and check visibility that way. But if i have no other choice i guess i could